# how to return filled array item in user defined class toString method?

Tags: java, arrays, class, tostring

the method should return all filled items from the array but instead, it returns the last item from the array.

```
public String toString() {

String result = "";

      for( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
      {
         result =  String.format("%d. %s\n", i+1, list[i]);  
      }
      return result; 
   }
```

Comment: replace `=` by `+=` maybe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are always replacing the value in `result` string with latest

```
result =  String.format("%d. %s\n", i+1, list[i]);  // replaces the value always with latest
```

So use use `StringBuilder` to append all values and then return it

```
public String toString() {

 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

  for( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
  {
     builder.append(String.format("%d. %s\n", i+1, list[i]));  
  }
  return builder.toString(); 
}
```